# Rotate to make paralel to another object

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to rotate text to make parallel to line. How to achieve that?

I know how to rotate using mouse, but I can't find how to rotate by entering angle value. Where is that function?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With your line selected, Type "R" or the click the Rotate tool. [image]

The rotate dialog window should pop up where you can enter the rotation by degrees.

[image]

[About Adobe Illustrator's Rotate Tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/rotating-reflecting-objects.html)